# Column lines not displaying when column type is specified (using pgfplotstable)

Tags: pgfplotstable, columns

I am in need of assistance, please.  I have spent several hours trying to solve this problem, but I can't see where it might be.  I'm new to pgfplotstable, but not new to LaTeX, but I am definitely at the limit of my ability.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

I have to write a report and then reformat it according to the requirements of several different clients.  One of these clients requires all tables to have all cell boundaries drawn, but the others do not.  I decided to use pgfplotstable because of the ability to set global options that I can incorporate into my various .cls files.  Unfortunately, it appears that when I define the column type justification (l, r, p{}, etc.), the modifier (`column type/.add={|}{}`) does not appear to work.  This is true both when it is written within the global options of `\pgfplotstableset` and under an individual table using `\pgfplotstabletypeset`.

My attempt at a minimum working example is as follows:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} 

\pgfplotstableset{ %for Client1
    every head row/.style={
        before row=\hline},
    after row={\hline},
    col sep = &,
    row sep=\\,
    string type,
    column type/.add={|}{}, %The client has requested every cell have lines.
    every last column/.style={column type/.add={}{|}},
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[htb!]
        \centering
        \caption{This table should have vertical lines around every cell, but doesn't.} 
        \pgfplotstabletypeset[
        columns/Task/.style={column type={l}},
        columns/Objective/.style={column type={p{8cm}}},
        ]{
            Task    &   Objective \\ 
            1 & This a work description of Task 1, and as such contains several sentences of text that must wrap within the cell. \\
            2 & This a work description of Task 2, and as such contains several sentences of text that must wrap within the cell. \\
            3 & This a work description of Task 3, and as such contains several sentences of text that must wrap within the cell. \\
        }
    \end{table}


    \begin{table}[htb!]
        \centering
        \caption{This table has the default column alignment and the global options apply correctly.} 
        \pgfplotstabletypeset[]{
            Task    &   Objective \\ 
            1       &   Short text that does not wrap \\
            2       &   Short text that does not wrap \\
        }
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Am I missing something obvious?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you want `|l|` instead of `l` and `p{8cm}|` instead of `p{8cm}`

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response!  I don't want to add the | directly into the tables because then all the different versions of the report will have the column lines.  I am after tables that are common to all the different report formats where ```column type/.add={|}{}``` will add the column lines only when needed.  Thanks.

Comment: OK I know nothing about the package but someone will answer:-)

Comment: This can't really work. The default `column type` is `r`. With `\column type/.add` you are changing this to `|r`.  But at the start of the table with the columns style you are then overwriting this.

Comment: Hello!  I found that it doesn't matter whether or not the ```column type/.add``` method is under the global options or within the  ```\pgfplotstabletypeset``` options _after_ the column types have been set. It appears to me to just not work correctly. Vertical lines are not aesthetically pleasing, so I can't find any examples in the manual for similar circumstances.